# Call between subroutines

Tags: fortran

I'm new to Fortran programming and I'm trying to understand the call between subroutines. So I wrote a simple program to test it

Here is my code

```
program dummy

    real, allocatable, dimension(:)         :: zz,yy

    call test2(zz,yy)

    print *, zz, yy

contains

    subroutine test1(ar1,ar2,arsum)
        real, dimension(:)                  :: ar1,ar2
        real, allocatable, dimension(:)     :: arsum
        allocate(arsum(size(ar1)+size(ar2)))
        arsum(1:size(ar1)) = ar1
        arsum(size(ar1)+1:size(ar1)+size(ar2)) = ar2

    end subroutine test1

    subroutine test2(sg1,sg2)
        real, dimension(3)              :: g1,g3
        real, dimension(4)              :: g2,g4
        real, allocatable,dimension(:) :: sg1,sg2,dum
        g1 = 1.0
        g2 = 2.0
        g3 = 3.0
        g4 = 4.0
        call test1(g1,g3,dum)
        sg1 = 2*dum
        call test1(g2,g4,dum)
        sg2 = 3*dum
    end subroutine test2

end program dummy
```

However this throws me the following error

```
forrtl: severe (151): allocatable array is already allocated
Image              PC                Routine            Line        Source             
dummy.exe          0000000000409B1C  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
dummy.exe          0000000000402E70  MAIN__                     26  dummy.f90
dummy.exe          0000000000402A2E  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
libc-2.23.so       00002B3E716C7830  __libc_start_main     Unknown  Unknown
dummy.exe          0000000000402929  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
```

The `test1` subroutine simply concatenates any two given arrays. `Test2` subroutine defines the arrays to be concatenated and does some algebra on the output and stores them in new arrays. The program `dummy` simply prints the new arrays.

What is it that I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's look at the flow of the program here.  There's some terminology involved here, but what is used can hopefully be explored through other documentation.

The main program calls the subroutine `test2` with a couple of arguments.  For the problem here, those arguments are of no interest.  Instead, look at the local (to the subroutine) variable `dum`.

`dum` is an allocatable array.  It starts life at execution of `test2` as not allocated.  It's first an (actual) argument to the call of `test1` and later as an (actual) argument to another call of `test1`.  So, what goes wrong?

Intent of the arguments is crucial here.  Really crucial.  One should read up on intents elsewhere before continuing with this answer.

So, we're now familiar with argument intents.

On entering the subroutine `test1` the dummy argument `arsum` has the same allocation status as the actual argument `dum`.  During `test1`'s execution there is an `allocate` statement.

An `allocate` statement may only attempt to allocate a thing not already allocated.  This is fine on the first call: on entry `dum`/`arsum` is not allocated.  During execution of the subroutine `arsum` is allocated, and this affects the allocation status of `test2`'s `dum`.

On the second call to `test1` `arsum` is now allocated because the actual argument `dum` is allocated.  The `allocate` statement fails, with the error message given, because of this.

That's the problem; how to fix?  We need to ensure `arsum` is not allocated.  There are two obvious ways:

- test the allocation status of `arsum` and respond accordingly (perhaps with a `deallocate`);
- deallocate `dum` between calls of `test1`.

But there is a possibly more appropriate way.  Note that `dum` is useful only as returning to `test2` the value of some operation.  Think back to intents: this is what `intent(out)` signifies.

If we rewrite the subroutine `test1` as

```
subroutine test1(ar1,ar2,arsum)
    real, dimension(:)                           :: ar1,ar2
    real, allocatable, dimension(:), intent(out) :: arsum
    allocate(arsum(size(ar1)+size(ar2)))
    arsum(1:size(ar1)) = ar1
    arsum(size(ar1)+1:size(ar1)+size(ar2)) = ar2
end subroutine test1
```

then, because of the `intent(out)`, attribute `arsum`/`dum` is automatically deallocated if it is allocated on entry.

Finally (and not shown), one could even consider using a function to return `arsum` or even use automatic arrays rather than allocatable ones.  Or, even Fortran 2003 automatic allocation and an array constructor:

```
subroutine test1(ar1,ar2,arsum)
    real, dimension(:)              :: ar1,ar2
    real, allocatable, dimension(:) :: arsum   ! Or with `intent(out)`
    arsum = [ar1,ar2]
end subroutine test1
```